# Hex Coded Decimal in Python

Tags: python, hex

I need to make a function that accepts an integer and returns a binary string of that integer encoded as Hex Coded Decimal, for later packing into a struct.

for example, I have written this:

```
def convert_int(x):
    """
    Accepts an integer, outputs a hexadecimal string in HCD format
    Caution! Byte order is ALREADY little endian!
    """
    result = b''
    while x > 0:
        hcd = chr(int(str(divmod(x, 100)[1]), 16))
        result = result + hcd
        x = divmod(x, 100)[0]
    return result
```

so `convert_int(1234)` would be `3412h` and so on. What is the most Pythonic and elegant way of writing this?

upd: made the function output little endian strings ready for packing.

Comment: The general idea on stackoverflow is that _you_ write some code and if it doesn't work you first search diligently using a well known search engine for possible solutions which you can copy or adapt to meet your needs, and only then if you don't get your code working you create a stackoverflow question and paste some code in which is minimal and executable and shows the problem you are having. Note the first part of that sequence: _you_ write some code.

Comment: Sorry guys, I screwed up with the string format. Of course it should be `0x1234` instead of `\x12\x34`

Comment: Nice one. Let's get this right. So you want e.g. `convert_to_hcd(1234)` to return the string `0x1234`? are you sure?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. I'm trying to solve it with manipulating the integer as a string but I think it's a bad idea and is not Pythonic anyway.

Comment: OK. Have you tried writing any python code yet?

Comment: updated with working Python code

Comment: Screwed up again. `convert_int(164)` for example should be `0164h`, not `1604h `

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert_to_hcd(num):
    chars = []
    while num:
        num, ones = divmod(num, 10)
        num, tens = divmod(num, 10)
        chars.append(chr(tens * 16 + ones))
    chars.reverse()
    return "".join(chars)

convert_to_hcd(1234)    # => returns '\x124' (which is correct because '\x34' == '4')
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the correct code for me is the following, **note that the byte order is reversed (little endian)**:

```
def convert_int(x):
"""
Accepts an integer, outputs a hexadecimal string in HCD format
Caution! Byte order is ALREADY little endian!
"""
result = b''
while x > 0:
    hcd = chr(int(str(divmod(x, 100)[1]), 16))
    result = result + hcd
    x = divmod(x, 100)[0]
return result
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def intToHex(num):
    numBin = [int(n) for n in str(num)]
    result = 0
    for n in numBin:
        result = result*16 + n
    return(hex(result))
```

this is clean

Comment: Um, no? `hex` converts an int to a string, which has *nothing at all* to do with what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Actually, what this function does can be done much more easily: `return '0x' + str(num)`. Refer to Yuri’s answer to see what he wants; it isn’t this. Granted the question wasn’t very clear.

Answer (score -1):

What about this little snippet... :)

`def convert_to_hcd(num): return "".join([ "\\x"+ (lambda i, k: ""+i+k if i !='m' else "0"+k)(i,k)  for i,k in zip((`num`if not len(`num`) % 2 else 'm' +`num`) [0::2], (`num`if not len(`num`) % 2 else 'm' +`num`[1::2])])`

Comment: That would be a great answer if the OP were trying to enter an obfuscated Python contest, but otherwise, it's too hard to follow :)

Comment: You don't say so... :)

Comment: But it actually works (if the OP has not rephrased the question).

Answer (score -3):

```
>>> hex(1234)
'0x4d2'
```

Google isn't your enemy...

Comment: Not the question he was asking, or it would return '0x1234'.